# stop character been inserted into input react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to detect which character base on user keyboard hence I use onKeyDown, but how do I stop ',' been inserted into the input element?

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {
    if (['188'].includes(e.keyCode)) {
      console.log("do something");
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      />
  );
```

Comment: I know this is doable but just wanted to remind you (from UX perspective) that you should probably add a clue for users to know about this like a helper text displays right under the input field and so we users is trying to type the non-valid characters, they know why it's gone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleKeyDown = (e: any) => {
  if (['188'].includes(e.keyCode)) {
      return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your includes doesn't work since **'188'** (string) isn't equal to **188** (number)
2. You can check the last inputed char in your **handleChange** function like so:

```js
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
  const value = e.target.value
  if (![','].includes(value[value.length-1])) {
      setInputValue(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the input in `handleChange` to decide to update new value or not
Try the code below:
Or [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-platform-11bwl?file=/src/App.js:0-568)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (!e.target.value.includes(",")) {
      setInputValue(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <input
      value={inputValue}
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```